# pass model data between razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, pass-data

I try pass model data between two Razor pages, data is not string or bool or int
data that i want pass to second page is a model,
i do taht with this way,

```
public class AskLibrarian
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string UserIp { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool ReadIt { get; set; }
    public bool Answer { get; set; }
    public string reciptCode { get; set; }
}
```

And on **Get method** pass data with this way:

```
 [BindProperty]
    public AskLibrarian AskLibrarian { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostQuestionAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        AskLibrarian.Answer = false;
        AskLibrarian.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        AskLibrarian.ReadIt = false;
        string userIp = $"{ HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIp))
        {
            userIp = "127.0.0.1";
        }


        AskLibrarian.UserIp = userIp;
        string rndNuber = Business.RandomNumberForQuestion.randCode;
        AskLibrarian.reciptCode = rndNuber;

        await _emailSenderService.SendEmailAsync(AskLibrarian.Email, AskLibrarian.FullName, rndNuber);
        _context.AskLibrarians.Add(AskLibrarian);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        Message = "your message sended";

        //return RedirectToPage("/Subfolder/Index", new { SFId = 7 });
        return RedirectToPage("/Subfolder/AskLibrarianCode", new { asklib = AskLibrarian });
    }
```

In **post** method in second page, like to get data on this way:

```
public void OnGet(Model.AskLibrarian asklib)
    {
        askLibrarianVM = new AskLibrarianVM
        {
            Answered = false,
            CreateDate = asklib.CreateDate,
            LastUpdate = asklib.CreateDate,
            RandomeCode = asklib.reciptCode,
            Status = false,

        };
    }
```

But ***asklib*** is empty ,I set a breakpoint at end of **Get method** and I sow that ***asklib*** if filled with valid values but in **post method** when i try to get data, asklib is **empty**
what is my mistake

Comment: You might look into `Session`. Here you can save data only for that user.

Comment: @PoulBak, Actually, I think TempData would be more appropriate for this task than Session in Razor Pages; however, the best answer is sunny's own answer, which he should accept as the Accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer was :

```
  return RedirectToPage("/Subfolder/AskLibrarianCode", AskLibrarian );
```

My mistake was

```
... new{asklib = AskLibrarian});
```

After more than two hours

Answer (score 0):

The lowest friction way is to `return View("SomeViewForTheModel", AskLibrarian)` and do your thing with a completely different view. Your second page controller action really isn't doing anything.

Otherwise, you'll have to save the ID associated with your `AskLibrarian` object, presumably in a database, and then look it up on the second page either by putting the ID in the URL path (be sure to validate the user should see it!), or by looking up in the database whatever is owned by the user.

Comment: i want send all data from first page to second page, another hand its not good way connect to the databse without any result when I can pass data directly, it's important for performance

Comment: Well, these are really your only options. Unless you're going to be handling extraordinary volume, worrying about hitting the database is a little premature.

Comment: @JeffPutz, I think you are referring to MVC, not Razor Pages, with speaking of Views, instead of Pages or Partial Pages, though here, the concept is much the same.